# Creating an array of double generic - Java

Tags: java, arrays, generics, casting

so I'm trying to create an array of a double generic class, but for some reason it is giving me an error.

Code:

```
Node<K, V>[] table = (Node<K, V>[]) new Object[10];
```

I'm receiving the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [HashCache$Node;

So, I was wondering why is it giving me this error and how can I fix it.

Comment: Don't use generics and arrays, they don't play nice together.

Comment: An Object is not necessarily a Node and even more, an array of objects is certainly not an array of nodes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `Object[]` ins't a `Node[]` - e.g., you could set an element of an `Object[]` to be `"Hello Word"`, which you could not do with a `Node[]`. TL;DR, you should be creating a `Node[]`:

```
Node<K, V>[] table = new Node[10];
```

Comment: You still need a cast. `Node<K, V>[] table = (Node<K, V>) new Node[10];`

Comment: @PeterLawrey without the cast, it's just an unchecked assignment warning. With the cast (`(Node<K,V>[])`, BTW, not `(Node<K,V>)`), it's an unchecked cast warning, so it's sort of a "choose your poison" scenario.